# Error when compiling a .NET application that uses DataSockets

Tags: .net, labview

I'm trying to build a .NET application that integrates a few LabView Virtual Instruments. I need to use the data sockets to integrate with them. I don't have and NI license (LabView or Measurement Studio), as the VI is provided by another company.

When I try to build my application, I get errors about missing license keys for three components:
NationalInstruments.Net.DataSocketServer, NationalInstruments.Net, Version=9.0.40.292
NationalInstruments.Net.DataSocket, NationalInstruments.Net, Version=9.0.40.292
NationalInstruments.Net.DataSocketSource, NationalInstruments.Net, Version=9.0.40.292

As I'm just trying to use the DataSocket, I'd like to avoid paying over USD 1'000.- for a complete development tool.

Is there any way of achieving this without violating any license?

Thanks

Comment: What LabVIEW version did you download, what license do you have (professional, basic, developer)?

Answer (score 1):

Without license you'll need someone to build a DLL, or .Net assembly for you, perhaps the vendor of the VIs.

Another option is to get the NI Measurement Studio , which include a .net Datasocket client. The standard version is €500, but I'm not sure if it has the datasocket client included.

Ton

Comment: The final answer is that a licence is required and the standard version is not sufficient. You need to have the Professional edition of NI Measurement Studio costing around USD 1500.-